# Swift 3, Display some lines of the HTML text

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I try to add html code inside webView:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

But last line displays cropped:

[image]

What is the best way to hide this cropped bottom line in my webView?

Comment: Can you add your html string here?

Comment: <div style="font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size: 11pt;"><div class="feed-description"><p>text text text <a href="..." target="_blank">link</a> text text text</p></div></div>

Comment: And you do not want to scroll your webView?

Comment: No, I have the button "Show all text" to go to another page with full text. I need to hide cropped bottom line here

Comment: So, you receive html code? May be I think that it is better to use UITextField. You can convert html to plain text. Have you thought about this? I can create the sample for you

Comment: No, I need to save <a> tags and bold words in text

Comment: Ok. Do you need to make this url clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you too use UILabel

### Full example

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var label: UILabel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        var bounds = view.bounds
        bounds.origin.y = 44
        bounds.size.height = 100
        label = UILabel(frame: bounds)
        label?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(label!)

        let filename = "HTMLPage.html"
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: nil) {
            do {
                let text = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                label?.attributedText = text.htmlToAttributedString
                label?.numberOfLines = 5
                label?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            } catch {
                print("Failed to read text from \(filename)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to load file from app bundle \(filename)")
        }
    }

}

extension String {

    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
            if let d = data {
                let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                                 options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                 documentAttributes: nil)
                return str
            }
        } catch {
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

> HTMLPage.html

```
<div style="font-family:'Helvetica'; font-size: 11pt;"><div class="feed-description"><p>The apple tree (Malus pumila, commonly and erroneously called Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.  <a href="..." target="_blank">link</a> It is cultivated worldwide as a fruit tree, and is the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central Asia, where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in Asia and Europe, and were brought to North America by European colonists. Apples have religious and mythological significance in many cultures, including Norse, Greek and European Christian traditions. <a href="..." target="_blank">link</a> text text text</p></div></div>
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vasily !